# Socket.IO 2.0 Listing all clients of a Room in a variable

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i need help. I research about this topic too much but i don't find any solution.

We can list all clients of a Room with code below;

```
io.of('/').in('room').clients((error, clients) => {
    if error throw error;
    console.log(clients);
});
```

My question is how can I show this `clients` result in a variable.

I tried these solutions:
1)

```
var list = io.of('/').in('room').clients ((error, clients) => {
    if error throw error;
    return clients;
}); // didn't work
```

2)

```
async function getList() {
    return await io.of('/').in('room').clients((error, clients) => {
        if error throw error;
        return clients;
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Just wrap it inside a `Promise`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande It didn't work. I think ıt's not an async operation.

Comment: Yes it works, how are you doing it?

Comment: `const getList = function () {
        io.of('/').in(room).clients(async (error, clients) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                var cls = await clients;
                debug(cls);
                return cls;
            });
        }
    debug(getList());`

Comment: Update the answer with the code, and that's not Promise wrapped

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I wrote my answer. The usage of my Code is this. Also, why i need to use Promise? Async/await is same, and It's syntax is Shooter than Promises.

Comment: Yes, if you want to convert `callback` to `Promise` you can't use `async/await` check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap the code inside a `Promise`

```
function getClients() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        io.of('/').in('room').clients((error, clients) => {
            if(error)
                return reject(error);

            resolve(clients);
        });
    });

}

(async() => {
    const clients = await getClients();
})();
```